# Changing 3 lines of code to php from c#

Tags: c#, php

Can any give me some idea on how to write the following code in PHP because the below code is in C#

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken", downloadTokenValue); 
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}",
desiredFileName)); 
response.Flush();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you would be better to ask "how to do X in php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this that way ,

```
<?php

    $downloadTokenValue = 'Youre Value';
    $desiredFileNames = 'Desired File Name Value';

    setcookie("fileDownloadToken", $downloadTokenValue, time()+3600);
    header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=$desiredFileNames"); 
    ?>
```

If you want to read that Cookie you can `echo $_COOKIE["fileDownloadToken"]`;